# spring mvc form <form:form > org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: spring

**web.xml**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>SpringMVCLoginFormValidate</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>LoginForm.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    </web-app>`
```

**spring-servlet.xml**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">



    <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.hr.controller" />


        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
            <property name="prefix" value="/" />  
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />

    </bean>
    </beans>
```

`

**LoginForm.jsp**

`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<style>
    .error { 
        color: red; font-weight: bold; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Spring MVC Form Validation Demo - Login Form</h2>
        <table border="0" width="90%">
        <form:form action="login" commandName="userForm" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Email: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="email" size="30"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </form:form>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

`
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package com.hr.controller;


import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.hr.model.User;


@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewLogin(Map<String, Object> model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("userForm", user);
        return "LoginForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin( @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
            BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "LoginForm";
        }

        return "LoginSuccess";
    }
}
```

**LoginSuccess.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Welcome ${userForm.email}! You have logged in successfully.</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**User.java**

```
package com.hr.model;

import org.hibernate.validator.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.Size;


public class User {
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 15, message = "Your password must between 6 and 15 characters")
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

am getting the error while debugging as

[image]

I had added all the jar files of spring 4.2.5 and Hibernate jars

how to solve the error???

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /LoginForm.jsp at line 21

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /LoginForm.jsp at line 21

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /LoginForm.jsp at line 21

18:     <div align="center">
19:         <h2>Spring MVC Form Validation Demo - Login Form</h2>
20:         <table border="0" width="90%">
21:         <form:form action="login" commandName="userForm" method="post">
22:                 <tr>
23:                     <td align="left" width="20%">Email: </td>
24:                     <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="email" size="30"/></td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:235)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    org.apache.jsp.LoginForm_jsp._jspService(LoginForm_jsp.java:107)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the request reaches the `Deployment descriptor` web.xml, To load the beans, we need `ContextLoaderListener` to be defined as a listener in the web.xml as defined below.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

To this we need to add a context param pointing to the spring bean file location

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: now its showing me error as    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /LoginForm.jsp at line 12

9:  
10:     <table>
11:     <tr>
12:         <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
13:         <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td> 
14:     </tr>
15:     <tr>

Comment: For the initial error in question, you need to place the listener. I dont see any first name in the login jsp that you posted in the question. If the error is different, raise another question please